# Stubborn reappearing of .bin files at project's node_modules

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

Every time I ran `yarn` or `yarn install` a `yarn` symlink file appears at `node_modules/.bin` which is waaaay older (0.27.5) than the current version installed globally (1.15.2). Thus, every time a need to run `yarn` which I always have to manually delete that symlink. Where does that file pop up from? How can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Mind including the `dependencies` in your `package.json` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

So now I know. It is WebStorm IDE that creates `.bin` folder and adds it to `PATH` to facilitate use of executables installed in `node_module` in the built-in terminal. Like an equivalent of npx.

[image]